# Print within Recursion function Python3

Tags: recursion, python-3.x

the point of my recursion function is to print integers in reverse order. 
    def rDisp(s):
        n=str(s)
        if n == "":
            return n
        else:
            return rDisp(n[1:]) + n[0]

```
def main():
    number=(int(input("Enter a number :")))
    rDisp(num)

main()
```

If within the main function I implement print(reverseDisplay(number)), it works, however, for the purpose of this code, I want the reverseDisplay function to do the printing. How would I go about implementing the print function into that block of code.

Thanks!

Comment: You use the print() function. I really don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Within the function, reverseDisplay(s), where do I implement the print function. Attempting to return print(reversedDisplay(n[1:])+n[0]) has not worked, and instead returns an error.

Comment: You don't return print(), you print().

Answer (score 1):

Untested code:

```
def reversePrint(s):
    if not s: 
        return
    print(s[-1])
    reversePrint(s[:-1])

def main():
    number=input("Enter a number :")
    reversePrint(number)

main()
```

Comment: Yeah thanks! That's basically it but I just messed around with it until I got all of the output on the same line

Answer (score 0):

Just  got it

```
def reverseDisplay(s):
    n=str(s)
    if n == "":
        return n
    else:
        reverseDisplay(n[1:])
        b=n[0]
        print(b,end='')
```